# How to restrict a has_many relationship to only 1 for a certain sub-type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a few models that have a has_many through relationship.

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participant_scores
  has_many :groups, through: :participant_scores
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participant_scores
  has_many :participants, through: :participant_scores
end

class ParticipantScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :participant
end
```

I have the need to have different types of groups, of which a participant can only be a member of 1 of that type.

For example, in a company there multiple departments and locations, but a person can only be associated with one department, and one location. On the other hand, there are generic groupings, that do not have a restriction, for example, there can be many social clubs, and a person could be a member of any number of them.

The groupings are all the same behaviorally, with the only difference being that some have the restriction around being only a member of 1.

I've contemplated using single table inheritance, but I've not figured out how to restrict it to only 1 association.
Parhaps add a `type` column, and then restrict with validations?
Use a scope?

None of those seem optimal, how can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a validation with scope

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness